# How to set default in php file

Tags: php, html-select

i have this code:

```
<select class='okin' name='netiotitmn' id='netiotitmi' disabled>
                                    <option> </option>
                                    <?php
                                        $x = 0; $y = 60;
                                        while($x <= $y) {
                                            $selected="";
                                            if ($x=9)      {$selected="selected";}
                                            echo "<option value='$x'  $selected>" . szpad($x) . "</option>";
                                            $x++;
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
```

I want set value 9 as a default but it not change everything. Supposedly the value 09 because i set it as default value if open this form and can change the value if the user select another value but it should 9 by default. it just blank and have drop down loop.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code :

```
if ($x == 9)      { $selected = " selected"; }
```

I changed the following code :

1. $x == 9 instead of $x = 9
2. { $selected = " selected"; } instead of { $selected = "selected"; }

It has space :

"selected" => " selected"

And then please replace the following code :

```
echo "<option value='9'".$selected.">" . szpad($x) . "</option>";
```

Comment: it not come out. i think it not related with space because the original code did not have space at all.

Comment: Please replace with the code. And then write the result here.

Answer (score 0):

You should never set a variable inside an `if` clause. If you want to check if `$x` equals `9`, then you have to use:

```
if($x == 9) { ... }
```

If you want to set all select options to 9, then you could do that in this part of your code:

```
echo "<option value='9'  $selected>" . szpad($x) . "</option>";
```

Comment: I want to make like this example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected. But i cant apply it to this coding. The different is it default show audi but mine is 09 .